# difference between executing SAS via Enterprise Guide and IOM from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sas

I can execute SAS code and read SAS datasets into .Net/C# datasets after using  the Integrated Object Model (IOM) described [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/003-30.pdf).

Just curious, is using .Net as a client of the SAS server any different to using Enterprise Guide (EG).

Basically our infrastructure team worry that this would be different to using EG. IMHO it is not but I am no expert on the SAS infrastructure.

So is there a difference to using EG as a client in comparison to using .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of course is - it depends.  On what you are doing and how you connect.  If you are using the workspace server, I'd propose the following to keep your infrastructure team happy:

- Ensure you clean up your sessions (don't leave them hanging in the event of a bug in your code, as an admin will then need to remove them)
- Use SSO (don't be managing passwords, and connect using client identity rather than a system account)
- Have some way of demonstrating that you aren't going to create enormous tables in WORK / submit long running queries / hog all the IO
- Consider how / if your application will need to change as a result of a SAS upgrade

Comment: Thanks. I am accessing the workspace server. Sorry if this was not clear. Btw some of these potential issues also exist with EG (e.g. create enormous tables etc.). Not sure how to use SSO but I think using an xml file containing the credentials is also fairly good practice.

Answer (score 1):

In one sense there is not much difference.  They both will connect to a SAS session and interact with that.

In another there is a world of differences.

EG is written by SAS and your IT group might feel more comfortable that it will work as intended.  But it is also just a general purpose user interface and so users can do all kinds of crazy things that could cause serious service degradation on your SAS servers.

Your .net application is not being written by SAS and so the developer might not know how to optimize the use of SAS properly.  But it is also more likely to be a fit for purpose project that can be designed and tested before it is deployed to users and so avoid the potential for overloading the SAS server.

Comment: True, in many ways a custom application can be much safer than EG